# How to validate the textbox first character is Alpha and second character numeric in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Basically I validate account number starting with uppercase character and second character  is numeric.

```js
function CheckDecimal(inputtxt) 
{ 
    var Upper  = /^[A-Z]/; 
    var number = /^[0-9]/;
    if (inputtxt.value.match(Upper)) {
        alert('uppercase only...')
        return true;
    } else if (inputtxt.value.match(number)) { 
        alert('numeric only...')
        return true;
    }
    else { 
        alert('Wrong...!')
        return false;
    }
}
```

hide preview

Basically I validate account number starting with uppercase character and second character  is numeric.

```js
function CheckDecimal(inputtxt) 
{ 
    var Upper  = /^[A-Z]/; 
    var number = /^[0-9]/;
    if (inputtxt.value.match(Upper)) {
        alert('uppercase only...')
        return true;
    } else if (inputtxt.value.match(number)) { 
        alert('numeric only...')
        return true;
    }
    else { 
        alert('Wrong...!')
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
let pattern = /^[A-Z]+[0-9]+([a-z0-9A-Z]{1,})?/
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you're checking for the first character as number, while checking for number pattern. Instead you need to provide `var number=/^[A-Z][0-9]/;` as the number should be the second one.

Or you could use javascript to check the first and second character

```
if (!inputtxt) {
  return;
}
const firstChar = inputtxt.charAt(0);

if (firstChar !== firstChar.toUpperCase()) {
  alert("first character should be uppercase");
}

if (inputtxt.length > 1) {
  const secondChar = inputtxt.charAt(1);

  if (isNaN(secondChar)) {
    alert("second character should be numeric");
  }
}
```